# bin2dec for 16 bit signed binary values (in google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, binary, decimal, twos-complement

In google sheets, I'm trying to convert a 16-bit *signed* binary number to its decimal equivalent, but the built in function that does that only takes up to 10 bits. Other solutions to the problem that I've seen don't preserve the signedness.

So far I've tried:

- bin2dec on the leftmost 8 bits * 2^8 + bin2dec on the rightmost 8 bits
- hex2dec on the result of bin2dec on the leftmost 8 bits concatenated with bin2dec on the rightmost 8 bits

I've also seen a suggestion that multiplies each bit by its power of 2, eliminating bin2dec altogether.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a custom function

```
function binary2decimal(bin) {
return parseInt(bin, 2);  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your binary number is in cell A2.

First, set the formatting as follows: **Format > Number > Plain text**.

Then place the following formula in, say, B2:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A2&"","-",""),"(\d)","$1|"),"|")*(2^SEQUENCE(1,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2&"","-","")),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2&"","-",""))-1,-1))*IF(LEFT(A2)="-",-1,1)))`

This formula will process any length binary number, positive or negative, from 1 bit to 16 bits (and, in fact, to a length of 45 or 46 bits).

What this formula does is `SPLIT` the binary number (without the negative sign if it exists) into its separate bits, one per column; multiply each of those by 2 raised to the power of each element of an equal-sized degressive `SEQUENCE` that runs from a high of the `LEN` (i.e., number) of bits down to zero; and finally apply the negative sign conditionally `IF` one exists.

If you need to process a *range* where every value is a positive or negative binary number with ***exactly 16 bits***, you can do so. Suppose that your 16-bit binary numbers are in the range A2:A. First, be sure to select all of Column A and set the formatting to "Plain text" as described above. Then place the following array formula into, say, B2 (being sure that B2:B is empty first):

`=ArrayFormula(MMULT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&"","-",""),"(\d)","$1|"),"|")*(2^SEQUENCE(1,16,15,-1)),SEQUENCE(16,1,1,0))*IF(LEFT(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""))="-",-1,1))`